# The use of first last and map to implement Reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, methods

I stumbled upon this code that is meant to redefine Array.prototype.reduce:

```js
function first(array, n){
  return n === undefined ? array[0] : array.slice(0, n);
}; 

function last(array, n){
  if(n> array.length){
    return array;
    }else{
      return n === undefined ? array[array.legnth -1] : array.slice(array.length - n, array.length);
      
};
  
  function map(collection, iterator){
    var arr = []; 
    each(collection, function(element, index){
      arr.push(iterator(element, index);
    });
     return arr;
  };
```

```js
function reduce(collection, rf, acc) {
    acc = acc === undefined ? first(collection) : acc;
    return last(map(collection, function (value) {
        acc = rf(acc, value);
        return acc;
    }));
}
```

However, I don't understand what array.last() is doing here. Can someone please explain. Thank you.

Comment: Array does not have native `last` function. Unless it's also an extension to array prototype. Based on your code, there's no `array.last()` call, all I can see is a `last` function. What last does is implemented in that javascript scope itself. You can find it your own.

Comment: where is `last` defined

Comment: You will have to show us the `first()`, `last()` and `map()` functions since those are not standard Javascript.  We could guess what they do, but answers here are a lot better if we don't have to guess.  Also, you asked about `array.last()`, but there is nothing like that in your code.  Please take some time to write/edit a clear question that contains all necessary information to understand what you are asking and what your situation is.  Right now, this question stands to be closed as "unclear what you're asking" because there's not enough information in it.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks for all your comments. I have added the information that you requested. Thanks for taking a look at this.

Comment: In `last()`, `length` is spelling wrong on this line: `array[array.legnth -1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
0:    function reduce(collection, rf, acc) {
1:        acc = acc === undefined ? first(collection) : acc;
2:        return last(map(collection, function (value) {
3:            acc = rf(acc, value);
4:            return acc;
5:        }));
6:    }
```

Here's a line by line for what's going on in your `reduce()` function:

Line 1: If no value is passed for `acc`, set it to the first value in the collection.

Line 2: Call `map()` on your collection which will iterate over the collection, calling a callback that calls `rf()` on each item of the collection.  `map()` creates a new array that is the collection of returned values from each time the iteration callback is called.   On the resulting array returned from `map()`, get the `last()` value from that array and return that as the final return result from `reduce()`.

Line 3: Set `acc` to be the result of `rf(acc, value)`.

Line 4: Return `acc` from the callback which `map()` will put into the array.

> However, I don't understand what `array.last()` is doing here. Can
>   someone please explain.

Assuming you mean `last(array)`, the function of your `last(array)` is to get the last item in an array.  If you pass a second argument to `last()`, then it gets the last N items from the array you pass in and returns that as a new array (you are not using this second capability).

---

The implementation of `reduce()` does not seem like it should use `map()` because there's no point in creating this internal array.  I would think this would be more efficient:

```
function reduce(collection, rf, initial) {
    var acc = (initial === undefined) ? first(collection) : initial;
    each(collection, function(value) {
        acc = rf(acc, value);
    });
    return acc;
}
```

---

If you want to more accurately mimic `Array.prototype.reduce()` where if no initial value is selected, then the first element in the array is used as the initial value and the iterator is not called for the first element in the array, then you could do this:

```
function reduce(collection, rf, initial) {
    var acc = initial, index = 0;
    if (initial === undefined) {
        acc = collection[0];
        index = 1;
    }
    for (; index < collection.length; ++index) {
        acc = rf(acc, collection[index]);
    });
    return acc;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to explain it. I agree. The use of map here seems redundant and unnecessary when you already have a callback. Using each seems like the ideal way to go about it.

Comment: Quick question- if you are iterating over the entire collection wouldn't the collection[0].  be iterated through twice?

Comment: @IvonneTerrero - Yes, it would.  That is not the behavior of Javascript's `Array.prototype.reduce()`, but you didn't offer a specification for the desired behavior so I didn't change that aspect of it.

Comment: @IvonneTerrero - Since it looks like you may be new here, if this answered your question, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark next to the best answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure.

Comment: @IvonneTerrero - I added an alternate implementation.

Comment: That is awesome. Thanks so much. I figured if you have the if statement inside each we can also assign acc = currentValue. But I get the idea. The initial question was because last and Map were confusing me. Thanks so much for all your help and guidance. :-)